# C# - Add data to object inside object

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have the following classes

```
public class manoeuvresID
{
    public string manName { get; set; }
    public int manID { get; set; }
}

public class testID
{
    public string testName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IList<manoeuvresID> manoeuvres { get; set; }
}
```

and want to add data into a new list of type testID

```
        HardCodedDatabase.testID testObjet = new HardCodedDatabase.testID();
        testObjet.testName = "test1";
        testObjet.manoeuvres = "man1";

        List<HardCodedDatabase.testID> listForTesting = new List<HardCodedDatabase.testID>();
        listForTesting.Add(testObjet);
```

the problem is that I don't know how to add values to the testobjet.manoeuvres

Comment: [Naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) are really helpful and important ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize the list(better via constructor) and then add an object:

```
testObjet.Manoeuvres = new List<ManoeuvresId>();
ManoeuvresId id = new ManoeuvresId();
id.ManId = 1;
id.ManName = "man1";
testObjet.Manoeuvres.Add(id);
```

Here's a possible constructor implementation(also fixed the naming issues).

```
public class TestId
{
    public TestId() : this(-1, null) { }
    public TestId(int id) : this(id, null) { }
    public TestId(string name) : this(-1, name) { }
    public TestId(int id, string name)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.TestName = name;
        this.Manoeuvres = new List<ManoeuvresId>();
    }

    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IList<ManoeuvresId> Manoeuvres { get; set; }
}
```

Then it's ensured that the list is always initialized and you can simplify it to:

```
TestId testObjet = new TestId(1, "test1");
testObjet.Manoeuvres.Add(new ManoeuvresId { ManId = 1, ManName = "man1" });
```

Comment: how can I add another TestObjet to the ListForTesting?             `TestObjet.testName = "test1";  
            ListForTesting.Add(TestObjet);  
            TestObjet.testName = "test2";  
            ListForTesting.Add(TestObjet);  
            combobox_testType.Items.Add(ListForTesting[0].testName);  
            combobox_testType.Items.Add(ListForTesting[1].testName);`

Comment: @peetman: you have to initialize a new `TestId`-instance: `testObjet = new HardCodedDatabase.testID(); testObjet.testName = "test2"; ListForTesting.Add(testObjet);`. 
`

Comment: @peetman: That's basic OOP. You need to understand the difference between a class, an instance of a class and a variable. If you have two test-objects you want two instances of this class.

Comment: @peetman, VBA is very lazy and lets you get away with doing some stupid things. because c# will not allow you to make those mistakes then it is much easier to write good programs. if you turn on option strict and explicit in VBA. then it will be much the same

Comment: @MikeT: i think you're confusing VB.NET with VBA

Comment: @TimSchmelter fairly sure i'm not, i've spent way too much time working in VB6 and VBA

Comment: @MikeT: but OP said that he is used to VBA and afaik there is no `option strict` in VBA, is it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ah see where you are coming from, i always mentally pair the 2 together so that i always check them no matter what version of VB I'm being subjected to ;) better to check for one that's not there than forget to turn it on when it is

Answer (score 2):

if you look at [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see is is a List, which has an add function

so you would do

```
testObjet.manoeuvres.Add(new manoeuvresID(){manName ="Something"});
```

note that you need to set manoeuvres to a new List (or other class that implements IList) first

Answer (score 1):

Define a list

```
testObjet.manoeuvres = new list<HardCodedDatabase.manoeuvresID>();
```

Create an object for manoeuvresId

```
    var anotherTestData = new HardCodedDatabase.manoeuvresID();
        anotherTestData .manName  = "something";
```

Add this object to testObj

```
testObjet.manoeuvres.Add(anotherTestData);
```

That's it.

So your code will look like this

```
 HardCodedDatabase.testID testObjet = new HardCodedDatabase.testID();
        testObjet.testName = "test1";
        testObjet.manoeuvres = "man1";
testObjet.manoeuvres = new list<HardCodedDatabase.manoeuvresID>(); 
testObjet.manoeuvres.Add(anotherTestData); 

var anotherTestData = new HardCodedDatabase.manoeuvresID();
            anotherTestData .manName  = "something"; 

        List<HardCodedDatabase.testID> listForTesting = new List<HardCodedDatabase.testID>();
        listForTesting.Add(testObjet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. You need to add `List<manoeuvresID>` in `testID` object.

```
testID testObjet = new testID();
testObjet.testName = "test1";

manoeuvresID man = new manoeuvresID();
man.manID = 1;
man.manName = "Mairaj";

testObjet.manoeuvres = new List<manoeuvresID>() { man };

List<testID> listForTesting = new List<testID>();
listForTesting.Add(testObjet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also :

```
   HardCodedDatabase.testID testObjet = new HardCodedDatabase.testID();
    testObjet.testName = "test1";
   testObjet.manoeuvres.Add(new manoeuvresID(){manName ="man1"});
    List<HardCodedDatabase.testID> listForTesting = new List<HardCodedDatabase.testID>();
    listForTesting.Add(testObjet);
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ValAppWPF.HardCodedDatabase.ManoeuvresID' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ValAppWPF.HardCodedDatabase.ManoeuvresID>'.

Comment: not yet. it does not recognise monoeuvresID(). I have to add HardCodedDatabase.manoeuvresID() and throws the error I wrote before